# How to redirect user back to the next request after login with sentry in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, sentry

I am using sentry to authenticate users in laravel 5.3. When the user clicks auth protected route is redirect to the login form. After login, the user is redirected to home page. 
How can I configure sentry in manner that the authenticated user is not redirected back to home page but instead to the original destination before login. Kindly assist I seem not to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called intended

```
return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
```

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. But if am not wrong, sentry redirects authenticated users to the home page. I need some assistance on how to redirect users to the URL they were attempting to access before login in SENTRY with laravel 5.3. If using laravel inbuild AUTH this will be default settings. How could I achieve this with SENTRY?

Comment: do you have any code to where your doing your authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help you --

You can try giving the url something like this `localhost:8000/something?url=anythingelse` so that after login change the redirect path to `$_GET['url']`.

Use a form rather than link to go to login page. Try this --

```
<form method="GET" url="{{ url('/some') }}?{{ Request::path() }}" id="login"></form>
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('login').submit()">Login</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Advaith. However in most cases in laravel the login form is called by a middleware. This will work in cases where the user clicks the login link. How about the middle ware which automatically call the login form when  a un-authenticated user attempts to access a URL that require login.